# Unable to find a suitable version for angular while running bower install command

Tags: angularjs, bower-install

I am getting the following message while running bower install command.

[image]

[image]

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.1.6",
  "dependencies": {
               "jquery": "2.1.0",
               "jquery-bridget": "*",
    "angular": "1.3.15",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.15",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.15",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.15",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.15",
    "angular-touch": "1.3.15",
    "angular-moment": "~0.6.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.6.0",
    "angular-masonry": "0.11.0",
    "js-cookie": "2.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.15",
    "angular-scenario": "1.3.15"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me here to how to proceed ahead.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the dependencies you are injecting requires different versions of angularJs. For resolving it, first find a suitable compatible version of angularJs. And then you can add `resolutions` to the object in your `bower.json` file and specify the component name & version to automatically resolve the conflict when running bower commands. Like this:

```
{
 "name": "test-app",
 "version": "1.1.6",
 "dependencies": {
           "jquery": "2.1.0",
           "jquery-bridget": "*",
     "angular": "1.3.15",
     "json3": "~3.2.6",
     "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
     "angular-resource": "1.3.15",
     "angular-sanitize": "1.3.15",
     "angular-animate": "1.3.15",
     "angular-cookies": "1.3.15",
     "angular-touch": "1.3.15",
     "angular-moment": "~0.6.2",
     "angular-loading-bar": "0.6.0",
     "angular-masonry": "0.11.0",
     "js-cookie": "2.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     "angular-mocks": "1.3.15",
     "angular-scenario": "1.3.15"
  },
  "resolutions": {
     "angular": "1.3.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. it helped me to fix the issue :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to a recent `angular-moment` version like `~0.10`

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly tell `bower` to install specific version of a dependency using the `resolutions` attribute. Like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.0",
    "jquery-bridget": "*",
    ...
}, 
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.8",
    ...
}
```